# Proving a relation with induction

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, induction

I have a problem:

Let $p_n$ be the $n:th$ prime number ($p_1=2,  p_2=3,  p_3=5$ and so on). With induction, show that $p_{n+2}>3n$ for each integer $n\geq1$.

I can't figure this out because the primes are confusing me, making me unable to show the inductive step.

Answer (score 5):

For $n=1$ we observe $p_1=2, p_2=3, p_3=5$. Thus, $p_{1+2}=5>3$. So, let $n\in \mathbf{N}$ be such that the relation holds for $n$, then we show $p_{n+3} > 3(n+1)$.

Now, $p_{n+3} \geq p_{n+2}+2 > 3n +2$, by the inductive hypothesis. So, $p_{n+3} \geq 3n+3 = 3(n+1)$. Since, $3(n+1)$ is composite, it cannot be prime. Hence, $p_{n+3} > 3(n+1)$.

So, the relation holds for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$.

My apologies for the blatantly incorrect statement I wrote before.

Comment: Downvoted, I especially dislike that you didn't give an argument for the false statement. $8009$ and $8011$ are both prime.

Answer (score 2):

$p_{(n+1)+2}=p_{n+3}\geq p_{n+2}+2\geq3n+3$ now explain why $p_{n+3}\neq 3(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by induction.

Let's start with the case $n=1$:

$p_{1+2}=p_3=5>3*1=3$

So the equality is true for $n=1$.

Now, we assume that the equality is true for the case $n-1$, that is,

$p_{n-1+2}=p_{n+1}>3(n-1)=3n-3$

and let's see that it is also true for n:

$p_{n+2}\geq p_{n+1}+2>3(n-1)+2=3n-1$; so $p_{n+2}\geq3n$

Now,you have to see that $p_{n+2}>3n$

Comment: -1 Check your last step $3(n-1) + 2 \not > 3n$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ we can verify that $p_3=5>3\cdot1$
Suppose that the statement holds true for $n$ meaning that $p_{n+2}>3n$. We will show that
this holds for $n+1$.
 We have $p_{(n+1)+2}=p_{n+3}$. We already know from the induction step that $p_{n+2}>3n$  which means $p_{n+2}\geq 3n+1$.
So if $p_{n+3}\leq 3(n+1)=3n+3$ we have only one  possibility: $p_{n+3}=3n+2$

> (or $p_{n+3}=3n+1$ which means that $p_{n+2}$ and $p_{n+3}$ coincide .
>   Also, if $p>3$ then $p$ cannot be  a multiple of $3$ so the case
>   $p_{n+3}=3(n+1)$ is rejected)

But this means that $p_{n+2}$ and $p_{n+3}$ are consecutive primes which is only possible if the primes are $2,3$ (we are already above $5$)
All at the above step arrive at a contradiction and so we must have only one possibility: $p_{n+3}>3(n+1)$

this proves the case for $n+1$ and so, for every $n$.